# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "mood" not found

Tags: node.js, solidity, artifacts, hardhat

```
PS E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD> npx hardhat run --network Goerli deploy.js
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "mood" not found.
    at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:478:11)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:593:19)
    at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:275:17)
    at Artifacts.readArtifact (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\artifacts.ts:58:26)
    at getContractFactory (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\helpers.ts:99:22)
    at main (E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\deploy.js:4:18)
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR WHY A  I GETTING I AM UNABLE TO CREATE THE ARTIFACTS OR SAY THE HARDHAT IS UNABLE TO CREATE IT,AS FAR AS I KNOW npx hardhat compile gives the artifact files but it was not in this case**

[my mood.sol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luAMB.png)

[my deploy.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imly5.png)

Answer (score 2):

Bruh Your Contract name is `Mooddcontract`
and in the deploy.js you are writing `mood`.

Change `const MOOD = await ethers.getContractFactory('mood')` into `const MOOD = await ethers.getContractFactory('Mooddcontract')`

I hope that will solve that problem IA.

[image]

[image]